# Libgdx Sprite not in the correct position over b2body

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have written some code which is meant to update the position of a sprite to the position of its corresponding box 2d body. Here is a link to a gif which shows what the program currently looks like when running:

[image]

The grey robot sprite is meant to be attached to the larger circle, and the black bat sprite is meant to be attached to the larger circle. Here is the line of code I used in my update() methods for each class which is meant to set the postion of the sprite as the program runs:

```
setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x*RoboiGame.PPM -getWidth()/2, 64);
```

Been at it for a few days now, can't seem to find a solution to this in any similar questions.

```
public void defineRoboi(){ 
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
bdef.position.set(960/RoboiGame.PPM,64/RoboiGame.PPM);
bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
b2body = world.createBody(bdef);
FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
shape.setRadius(10/RoboiGame.PPM);
fdef.shape = shape;
b2body.createFixture(fdef);
fdef.filter.categoryBits = RoboiGame.ROBOI_BIT;
fdef.filter.maskBits = RoboiGame.GROUND_BIT;}
```

This is my define method where I create my b2body. My PPM value is 100.

This is my player class, called 'Roboi': https://pastebin.com/mhsmssZx

This is the main game class:
https://pastebin.com/SpqcXvBp

This is the PlayScreen class:
https://pastebin.com/eqSS7CdA

Comment: What is RoboiGame.PPM ? Pixels per meter?

Comment: Yes, thats my Pixels per meter value. At the moment that value is 100.

Comment: Is the body really where it is displayed in your gif? Or is there just some inconsistency between your renderer and the box2d debug rendering?

Comment: I'd suggest to post full code if you were not able to solve this yet

Comment: The characters are not meant to move vertically at any stage, so I thought a constant could be used. Without multiplying by PPM, the sprite appears on the very left of the screen and moves very little.

Comment: I've added in some links to relevant classes in my game.

Comment: It looks like you are over complicating your code by using some imaginary "pixel" units. Don't do that, just use the same units, eg meters, throughout your entire code. Read this: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/.